# Using custom type props in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a type that looks like this:

```
type MyType = string;
```

I then want to restrict a prop to only take `MyType`, not a regular string or anything else.

But even when I type it like this:

```
interface MyProps
{
   key: MyType
}
```

the component still accepts takes a regular string as a parameter. I guess it's because MyType equals a string.

```
<MyComponent key="regularstring" />
```

How do I make the component to only accept 'MyType' type of strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to provide explicit string for the type. for eg

```
type MyType = 'myType';
```

this will only accept the value of `myType`

for multi values

```
type MyType = 'myType' | 'regular'; // will support both values
```